# Why does this Spring rest API enforce username but not password

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

when I use postman to submit a get request to

`http://localhost:8080/students/

If I use credentials `admin1` `123`, I get a 401 error.

If I use credentials `admin` `123`, the reuqest returns a list of users.

If I use credentials `admin` `1234`,  the request also returns a list of users.

am I not validiating password correctly?

```
      @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        @Override
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                    .username("admin")
                    .password("123")
                    .roles("ADMIN")
                    .build();
            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
    }


    @RestController
public class StudentResource {

    @Autowired private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @GetMapping("/students")
    public List<Student> retrieveAllStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

}

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("123")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
}

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

}


data.sql
        insert into student
        values(10001,'Ranga', 'E1234567');

        insert into student
```

Comment: Put the endpoint code in your question so we can help you.

Comment: I don't believe you

Comment: @andreybleme added more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path in the controller dosen't match the path in the configuration.

Comment: Glad I helped. Consider upvoting or accepting my answer. Cheers.